# add Eventhandler to a shape inside a DataTemplate by code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have the following DataTemplate which is defined in a Resources.xaml which holds my Visual Templates for my programs (thats why no Eventhandlers are included here)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PointTemplate">
    <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Width="8" Height="8" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1.5" Fill="White" Visibility="{Binding DataItem.Visibility}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

then its used for a visual in Code by loading it from my Resources:

```
...
line.PointTemplate = (DataTemplate) Application.Current.Resources["PointTemplate"];
```

Now i want to add an EventHandler and Cursor to the Ellipse inside the PointTemplate (=DataTemplate). 
but.. how do i do this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can change the cursor from xaml like: 'Cursor="Hand"', and what event do you want to handle ?

Comment: i want to handle the MouseDown event. 
setting the cursor in the xaml is sure possible but not all instances which use this template are supposed to get it (and duplicating the template to have a copy with the cursor isnt really nice either)

Comment: Then maybe you can use something like a Trigger or DataTrigger to change the Cursor only when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to handle the event is to use a Button with a command:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PointTemplate">
    <Button Command="Zoom">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Width="80" Height="80" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1.5" Fill="White"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

And you can add a handler for the command accordingly.